# How to assign a column inside a function?

Tags: r

I have this function in the dataset *ecr*, that takes a column of *ecr* as a string and changes each value appropriately:

```
ctrc <- function(x) {
  (ecr[[x]]-mean(ecr[[x]]))/sd(ecr[[x]])
}
```

It then prints the values to the console. I would like to assign the results of this function to a column in *ecr*. However, nothing that I have tried has resulted in this happening. Some examples:

```
ctrc <- function(x) {
  ecr$var2 <- (ecr[[x]]-mean(ecr[[x]]))/sd(ecr[[x]])
}
```

```
mctrc <- function(y) {
   mutate(ecr, var2=ctrc("y"))
}
```

How do I get this function to work, and why don't these versions work?

Answer (score 0):

The function returns some value/output which is either defined under return() or the last executed syntax. In this case, it will be `(x-mean(x)) /sd`. So the variable you are looking for to create can be assigned to the new var as below:

```
#function defn::
ctrc <- function(x) {
  (ecr[[x]]-mean(ecr[[x]]))/sd(ecr[[x]])
}

#assign in var
ecr$newvar=ctrc(oldVarName)
```

where nevar: new variable name which you are trying to create,
oldVarName : variable on which you want to apply this function

As best practice one should have return statement in function to ease the interpretability of code:

```
ctrc <- function(x) {
  y=(ecr[[x]]-mean(ecr[[x]]))/sd(ecr[[x]])
  return(y)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very strong reason, don't pass column name as input to the function, pass the values instead.

```
ctrc <- function(x) (x-mean(x))/sd(x)
```

you can then call it as :

```
library(dplyr)
ecr %>% mutate(var2 = ctrc(y))
```

OR for multiple columns

```
ecr %>% mutate(across(c(y, z), ctrc))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but piping was another attempt that didn't work.

Comment: if this answer does not work for you. Can you add an example to your post and show expected output based on that?